# Rails / RSpec match a Rails match route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I am having some trouble writing a spec for some of my routes. I run into this problem with pretty much any rails match route. Here's the code:

in routes.rb

```
match "/:id" => "home#order"
```

in home_controller.rb

```
def order
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => 'order' }
  end
end
```

in home_controller_spec.rb:

```
it "should render the order layout" do
  get :order
  response.layout.should == 'layouts/order'
end
```

rake routes has:

```
/:id(.:format)                      {:controller=>"home", :action=>"order"}
```

However, the spec is throwing this exception:

```
  1) HomeController when not signed in should render the order layout
     Failure/Error: get :order
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"home", :action=>"order"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
get :order
```

would only work if you were using named routes. Try just

```
get "/1"
```